# Rasterize vector file using gdal.RasterizeLayer() without losing attribute information in python

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, ogr, rasterization

Is it possible to rasterize a vector file with `gdal.RasterizeLayer()`, saving attribute as Raster value ? Like gdal_rasterize can do with :

```
gdal_rasterize -a attribute -ts rasterXsize rasterYsize -l layername shapePath rasterPath
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220749/rasterizing-a-gdal-layer), we can rasterize the attribute in color levels (0-255) on the 3 bands, but my objective is to keep the attribute value intact on a single raster band. I found many other examples [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/alg/rasterize.py) but None fit my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using

[Programmatic raster-vector calculation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53417/programmatic-raster-vector-calculation?rq=1)

I had some troubles using directly gdal.RasterizeLayer() on layers like propose [here in the cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#convert-an-ogr-file-to-a-raster) but it seems that using "MEM" data source and finally writing it on the disk is maybe better.

My solution (which is one of many possible solutions)

```
def rasterizer(shapePath, rasterPath, attribute, gridModelPath):
    '''Rasterize a shapefile using its attribute value
        @param shapePath    Input shapefile
        @param rasterPath   Output rasterfile
        @param attribute    Attribute fieldname (string)
        @gridModelPath      grid used to as reference'''
    # Import data, geotransform and projection from the model grid
    data, geotransform, prj_wkt = rasterReader(gridModelPath)
    RasterYSize, RasterXSize = data.shape

    # Import data from the vector layer
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    vector_source = driver.Open(shapePath,0)
    source_layer = vector_source.GetLayer(0)

    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'MEM' ).Create( "", RasterXSize, RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform( geotransform )
    target_ds.SetProjection( prj_wkt )
    # Rasterise!
    err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer,
        options=["ATTRIBUTE=%s" % attribute ])
    if err != 0:
        raise Exception("error rasterizing layer: %s" % err)
    data = target_ds.ReadAsArray()
    # Write your data on the disk
    rasterWriter(data, rasterPath, geotransform, prj_wkt, gdal.GDT_Int32)
```